# WebSocket in the app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I do not speak English well, so sorry. Here is my working WebSocket, which works in the browser. I need to write it to my application (react native). Please help me write it. I can not figure it out for two days already.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>charset</title>
 </head>
<script>


reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function() {
    alert(reader.result);
}
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://77.87.917.23:8023", 'binary');
socket.onopen = function() {
  alert("Соединение установлено.");
};
socket.onclose = function(event) {
  if (event.wasClean) {
    alert('Соединение закрыто чисто');
  } else {
    alert('Обрыв соединения');
  }
  alert('Код: ' + event.code + ' причина: ' + event.reason);
};
socket.onmessage = function(event) {
  reader.readAsText(event.data);
};


</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you define your problem a bit better?

Comment: Please share your react native component where you want to use websocket.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it by this way.You can create instance of socket in component constructor or componentDidMount function.

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = io.connect("http://77.87.917.23:8023",transports: ['websocket']});

socket.on('connect', (socket) => {
  console.log('Sono -> connect.');
});

//you can call this function on button click or any other way from the react native component
function sendData(data)
{
    socket.emit(event_name,data);// catch this event on server side
}

//This event is fire from server side
socket.on('exchange', function(data){
  console.log("share parametere",data);
});
```

If you have any query then feel free to ask me.

Comment: do you have telegramm?

Comment: Martazanov Djambulat please share react native your component where you want to add socket programming.